# C# How to add custom attributes to html string?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have string contains html and i want to add to some attributes to that html string.

Is there any html parser/editor class in .NETi can use to do that?

For example i have tags `<script>` in that html and i want to add attribute `src="somesrtpath"` to all of them.

I would have probably just have one case where html would contain just two script tags in the beginning something like

```
 <script type="text/javascript" `<add hrere src>` >
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" `<add hrere src>`>
 </script>
```

Basically what i would want to do is just to say to some function - here is html for each script tag add this src

Comment: are you in windows forms or ASP.NET? do you have the html really only in a string or in a page?

Comment: @Davide Piras i have a piece of html generated by lets say some `blackbox`, so after it is generated that i want to modify that as i describe in my question, basically i am constructing `htmlhelper`

Answer (score 0):

if your HTML is in a string you surely can parse it and manipulate it with the:

[HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), plenty, really, plenty of examples here in SO...

Comment: so there is no way to do that without any third party dll's?

Comment: there is but you are basically implementing your own parses which will most likely break and never be at the same level. Show some use cases editing your question, if all you need to do is trivial like adding  src to script tag than you can do it yourself but if you need more, let's reuse and not reinvent the same thing all over...

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the HTML as a string then you could use `.IndexOf("<script ")` to find the scripts.

```
for (int scriptStart = htmlContent.IndexOf("<script "); scriptStart > -1; scriptStart = htmlContent.IndexOf("<script ",  scriptStart + 1))
{
    // Find position of the type= bit.
    int typeAttributeIndex = htmlContent.IndexOf("type=\"text/javascript\"", scriptStart);

    htmlContent.Insert(typeAttributeIndex + 22, " src=\"something\"");
}
```

This is a bit quick and dirty. If you want to clean it up a bit more you could use a regular expression to make sure you are matching the script tag correctly. You could also match the end of the script block looking for the > but just be aware that script tags can be `<script ... ></script>` or sometimes `<script ... />`. Putting the src after the / would cause an issue.